# IncompleteAnnotationException when I add perfomance Firebase library

Tags: annotations, dagger, firebase-performance

I want to implement the Performance Firebase SDK in my Android app.
I add this to gradle

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.1.1'
```

But when I compile it, I get this error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.annotation.IncompleteAnnotationException: dagger.Provides missing element type
```

What could I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the solution, I update Dagger to 2.12 (from 2.5)